# SpriteKit How to add laser beam and resize it at collision point

Tags: sprite, collision, detection

I'm developing my first game with SpriteKit and I need to shoot a laser beam. I don't know how to do this since I don't know the size of the laser sprite, does it have to be with size of the screen height and crop the image when a collision is detected? can anyone point me to the right directions please? Have no idea about this XD

Thanks for your comments :D

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by line-of-sight detection system described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW32) in the section Searching for physics bodies :

Useful method would be  [enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart:end:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsWorld/enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart:end:usingBlock:) from SKPhysicsWorld class which enumerates all the physics bodies in the scene that intersect a ray.

Basically you have to set start point and search for end point using the method above.When you know where is the intersection point(end point of laser beam) you can easily draw it.

Comment: So when an end point is detected I just draw the laser with that height? What happens with the sprites? does it have to be one resizable sprite?

Answer (score 1):

This is a way late response, but I've got a really nice solution. Here's what it looks like (Swift 3):

In my code I'm calling this when I rotate the node I want the laser to shoot out of:

```
self.laser = SKShapeNode()
laser.lineWidth = 6
laser.glowWidth = 8
laser.strokeColor = .red

let _ = isTargetVisibleAtAngle(startPoint: startPoint, angle: selectedBeam!.zRotation + (CGFloat.pi / 2), distance: frame.size.height)
```

And this is the method. Obviously you put in whatever angle you want. The "foundOne" thing is so that it stops on the first object if that ray crosses through multiple targets

```
func isTargetVisibleAtAngle(startPoint: CGPoint, angle: CGFloat, distance: CGFloat) -> Bool {
    let rayStart = startPoint
    let rayEnd = CGPoint(x: rayStart.x + distance * cos(angle),
                         y: rayStart.y + distance * sin(angle))

    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.move(to: rayStart)
    path.addLine(to: rayEnd)
    laser.path = path

    var foundOne = false
    let _ = physicsWorld.enumerateBodies(alongRayStart: rayStart, end: rayEnd) { (body, point, vector, stop) in
        if !foundOne {
            foundOne = true
            let p = CGMutablePath()
            p.move(to: rayStart)
            p.addLine(to: point)
            self.laser.path = p
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

[image]

[image]